# autocomplete issue, does not open if same search term - jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

The autocomplete made by jquery seems to have a very small issue, yet disturbing,

I've implemented it to many input fields over time, yet I always find the following annoying:

If you search for a term on it, say "book", then it opens well showing up book rendered in the li, alright, but now if you quickly make control + a to select all, then control + x to cut, then control + v to paste, you'll notice what happens, the autocomplete just does not open.

It seems it does not search if the term entered is the same, that's an ok mechanism in terms of pressing other keys that are different to the term, just like the ctrl key or if you were to blur off the autocomplete and the focus once again, you also don't necessarily need for it to search, but if you erase the characters (term) and then retype the exact same characters, mostly I've tried by performing the ctrl + a, ctrl + x, ctrl + v keys combination, then the autocomplete remains closed.

Which seems a bit awkward, I wondered what to change to make it "open" if the search term is still the same that from what was last searched.

Thanks to anyone who has a solution for this.

Comment: wrap the auto complete in a text input change function $('.input').change(..)

Comment: yes, it seems that works, `$(document).on('change','.ui-autocomplete-input',function(){
$(this).autocomplete('search',$(this).val());
});`

Comment: ok rushing to put it as an answer ! ;)

Comment: Why do you think pressing Ctrl+a then Ctrl-x to cut and paste it again should trigger a change event on text field. Autocomplete is to help in completion as its definition says.

Comment: So that you can end up selecting something, maybe you think, ok I don't want to lookup for this, then you select it and cut it, then you think, oh, okay, it was the search term I was really looking for, then you paste, and whoops, no results, so if you don't know that you must delete the last character you entered and retype or wait for results for your string without one character then you're lost, so that's why

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use

```
    $(document).on('change',
                   '.ui-autocomplete-input',
                   function(){
                   $(this).autocomplete('search',$(this).val()); 
                   });
```

Comment: @charlietfl too fast on the trigger , change will evaluate if there is change or not , no matter what !!!! in case of text field it will trigger when pasting text .. but thats only when your off focus . here is a simple gift http://jsfiddle.net/D77nV/

Comment: just like i said...you have to blur from field for change to fire... does not fire simply with paste

Answer (score 1):

This handles paste with out need to blur.

```
$(document).on('input propertychange',
               '.ui-autocomplete-input',
                function() { 
                 $(this).autocomplete('search',$(this).val()); 
                });
```